# Stop slideshow onmouseover javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the slideshow script, I want it to stop when mouse move over. But i dont know what to add on it. I've tried to look for it online, but all of them doesn't work:(

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var dimages=new Array();
var numImages=2;
for (i=0; i<numImages; i++)
{
dimages[i]=new Image();
dimages[i].src="/v/vspfiles/assets/images/image"+(i+1)+".jpg";
}
var curImage=-1;
function swapPicture()
{
if (document.images)
{
var nextImage=curImage+1;
if (nextImage>=numImages)
nextImage=0;
if (dimages[nextImage] && dimages[nextImage].complete)
{
var target=0;
if (document.images.myImage)
target=document.images.myImage;  
if (document.all && document.getElementById("myImage"))
target=document.getElementById("myImage");

if (target)
{
target.src=dimages[nextImage].src;
curImage=nextImage;
}
setTimeout("swapPicture()", 4000);
}
else
{
setTimeout("swapPicture()", 1000);
}
setTimeout("swapPicture()", 4000);
//-->
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is not the "please do this for me" help desk.

Comment: You should learn about event listeners, and use the `onmouseover` event to perform the necessary steps to stop your slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info provided ( only the javascript at this point ).  The slideshow script is dependent on 
`setTimeout();`

The code responsible for stopping setTimeout(); is

`clearTimeout();`

Add the mouse event(s) to the slideshow and call clearTimeout(). As for the mouse events and best practices check SO for more instructions.

Here is one reference about setTimeout().

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Please post HTML for better and more accurate code on the mouse events.